# simple elevator in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a solution to the following challenge question found on codewars.com:

There is a house with 4 levels. In that house there is an elevator. You can program this elevator to go up or down, depending on what button the user touches inside the elevator.

valid levels can be only these numbers: 0,1,2,3

valid buttons can be only these strings: '0','1','2','3'

possible return values are these numbers: -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3

If the elevator is on the ground floor(0th level) and the user touches button '2' the elevator must go 2 levels up, so our function must return 2.

If the elevator is on the 3rd level and the user touches button '0' the elevator must go 3 levels down, so our function must return -3.

If the elevator is on the 2nd level, and the user touches button '2' the elevator must remain on the same level, so we return 0.

We cannot endanger the lives of our passengers, so if we get erronous inputs, our elevator must remain on the same level. So for example:

- `goto(2,'4')` must return 0, because there is no button '4' in the elevator.
- `goto(4,'0')` must return 0, because there is no level 4.
- `goto(3,undefined)` must return 0.
- `goto(undefined,'2')` must return 0.
- `goto([],'2')` must return 0 because the type of the input level is array instead of a number.
- `goto(3,{})` must return 0 because the type of the input button is object instead of a string.

I can came up with the following code but I am failing about 40% of the test case. Can someone tell me where I am wrong with my logic:

```
function goto(level,button){
    var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    var result = 0

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
            if(level === arr[i] && button === arr[j]){
                if(level < button){
                    result = level + button;
                }else{
                    result = button - level;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am refactored my code, but I am still failing 1 of 31 test cases with the following message given:

Expected: 0, instead got: 1

Refactored code:

```
function goto(level,button){
var valid = [0, 1, 2, 3];
button = Number(button);

if (typeof level === 'number' && typeof button === 'number') {
  for(var i = 0; i < valid.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < valid.length; j++){
        if(level === valid[i] && button === valid[j]){
               return button - level;
          }
       }
   }
 }
  return  0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is because level is a number, however button is a string. In javascript, because of type conversions :

```
3 - '2'; // return 1 
3 + '2';  // return '32';
```

Use the function `Number()` to convert your buttons string to a number, and you will have the true add behavior that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should do data format check first and also make it too complicated in calculating the result.

It should work as below.

```
function goto(level,button){
    var floors = [0, 1, 2, 3];

    var level_num = parseInt(level);
    var button_num = parseInt(button);

    if (typeof floors[level_num] == 'undefined' || typeof floors[button_num] == 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }

    return button_num - level_num;
}
```